# Hide current QMainWindow when next QMainWindow is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have multiple windows in a Python GUI application using PyQt5.
I need to hide current window when a button is clicked and show the next window.
This works fine from WindowA to WindowB but I get an error while going from WindowB to WindowC.

I know there is some problem in initialization as the initialization code in WindowB is unreachable, but being a beginner with PyQt, i can't figure out the solution.

WindowA code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from WindowB import Ui_forWindowB
class Ui_forWindowA(object):
     def setupUi(self, WindowA):
          # GUI specifications statements here
          self.someButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
          self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenWindowB)
          # More GUI specifications statements here
     def retranslateUi(self, WindowA):
          # More statements here
     def OpenWindowB(self):
          self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
          self.ui = Ui_forWindowB()
          self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
          WindowA.hide()
          self.window.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     WindowA = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     ui = Ui_forWindowA()
     ui.setupUi(WindowA)
     MainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

WindowB code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from WindowB import Ui_forWindowB
class Ui_forWindowB(object):
     def setupUi(self, WindowB):
          # GUI specifications statements here
          self.someButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
          self.someButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenWindowC)
          # More GUI specifications statements here
     def retranslateUi(self, WindowB):
          # More statements here
     def OpenWindowB(self):
          self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
          self.ui = Ui_forWindowC()
          self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
          WindowB.hide() # Error here
          self.window.show()

# The below code doesn't get executed when Ui_forWindowB is called from A
if __name__ == "__main__":
     import sys
     app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
     WindowB = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
     ui = Ui_forWindowB()
     ui.setupUi(WindowB)
     MainWindow.show()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works fine from A to B where

```
WindowA.hide() # Works Properly
```

While calling WindowC from WindowB

```
WindowB.hide() # Shows error: name 'WindowB' is not defined
```

I understand that the initialization isn't done as the "if" statement doesn't get executed.

How to get this working?
I have many more windows to connect in this flow

Comment: What `if` statement? there aren't any in your code except in `__main__`

Comment: @OmarEinea Yes the same if statement in the file for WindowB doesn't get called so the name WindowB doesn't get initialized & finally WindowB.hide() doesn't work

Comment: show us WindowB code then

Comment: @OmarEinea the code is same as WindowA....still edited for reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a Python script, the first file executed will be assigned the name `__main__`, therefore, if you first execute `WindowA` the code inside the block `if __name__ == "__main__"` gets executed and the application is started using `WindowA` as the main window, similarly if you execute your `WindowB` script first, the application will be started using`WindowB` as the main window.

You cannot start two applications within the same process so you have to choose which one you want to be the main window, all the others will be secondary windows (even if they inherit from `QMainWindow`).

Nevertheless, you should be able to instantiate new windows from a method in your main window.

As a good practice, you could create a main script to handle the initialization of your application and start an empty main window that will then handle your workflow, also, you may want to wrap your UI classes, specially if they are generated using Qt creator, here is an example:

**main.py**

```
import PyQt5

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from views.main_window import MainWindow


class App(QApplication):
    """Main application wrapper, loads and shows the main window"""

    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super().__init__(sys_argv)

        # Show main window
        self.main_window = MainWindow()
        self.main_window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(sys.argv)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main_window.py**

This is the main window, it doesn't do anything, just control the workflow of the application, i.e. load `WindowA`, then `WindowB` etc., notice that I inherit from Ui_MainWindow, by doing so, you can separate the look and feel from the logic and use Qt Creator to generate your UI:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow
from views.window_a import WindowA
from views.window_b import WindowB
from widgets.main_window import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    """Main application window, handles the workflow of secondary windows"""

    def __init__(self):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)

        # start hidden
        self.hide()

        # show window A
        self.window_a = WindowA()
        self.window_a.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.window_a_closed)
        self.window_a.show()


    def window_a_closed(self):
        # Show window B
        self.window_b = WindowB()
        self.window_b.actionExit.triggered.connect(self.window_b_closed)
        self.window_b.show()

    def window_b_closed(self):
        #Close the application if window B is closed
        self.close()
```

**window_a.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow
from widgets.main_window import Ui_forWindowA

class WindowA(Ui_forWindowA, QMainWindow):
    """Window A"""

    def __init__(self):
        Ui_forWindowA.__init__(self)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)

        # Do some stuff
```

**window_b.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QMainWindow
from widgets.main_window import Ui_forWindowB

class WindowA(Ui_forWindowB, QMainWindow):
    """Window B"""

    def __init__(self):
        Ui_forWindowB.__init__(self)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)

        # Do some stuff
```

Hopefully should give you an idea to get you going.